# AB/n Testing vs ANOVA

Tags: hypothesis-testing, anova

I would like to run some comparison analysis for sales between 5 different marketing campaigns and see which of these campaigns result in highest sales.

1. I am wondering if it is possible to use ANOAV test instead of running AB test. 
   It seems that ANOVA test is having a strict pre-conditions such as normality of distributions for each group, as well as homogeneity of variances. While AB test can handle the cases where the data is not normally distributed or homogeneous. 
   I would prefer to use ANOVA analysis as it makes it possible to run multiple comparison at once for more than two marketing campaigns, while AB testing can handle only two groups at a time.
2. During my google search, I also encounter AB/n testing, however, I am not sure how to implement it in python. Is it basically doing AB test on all combinations of two groups chosen from N groups?
3. If the normality and homogeneity conditions are not fulfilled, it wouldn't be possible to use ANOVA. Also if there are 5 groups the risk of type I error would be high(1-0.95 ^ 5 = 23%). Is there any other methods that maybe helpful in this case?

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! What exactly do you mean by AB testing? I would consider ANOVA (granted, on two groups instead of $3+$) and related regression ideas fit right in with AB testing.

Comment: Thanks!
AB testing is a convenient method for comparing two groups, control group and test group after changing a parameter between them and trying to see how it has an impact on the results. There is no pre-condition for using this method.
in this case, I'd like to compare how 5 different marketing campaign has impacted the sales.  and which one has been the most successful one.

Comment: What do you mean by a “pre-condition”?